# Is soundcloud web widget API outdated?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am trying to use soundcloud widget API(https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget)

And I want to get data about the tracks included in a set.

but all the other methods except widget.getSounds() and widget.getCurrentSound seem to be working.

I do understand that the getters are asynchronous and I am using a callback.

plus, I've found that sound object is not a simple array so I've tried other methods but failed..

any help or insights please

```
widget
_ {}

widget.getVolume(function(ret){console.log(ret)});
_ {}
VM5139:1 50

widget.getDuration(function(ret){console.log(ret)});
_ {}
VM5164:1 255057

widget.getPosition(function(ret){console.log(ret)});
_ {}
VM5190:1 92164.92599999999

widget.getCurrentSound(function(ret){console.log(ret)});
_ {}
VM2993:3 Uncaught TypeError: currentSound.get is not a function
    at _.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:47)
    at m (sc.js:1)
    at w (sc.js:1)
(anonymous) @ VM2993:3
m @ sc.js:1
w @ sc.js:1

widget.getCurrentSound(function(ret){console.log(ret.title)});
_ {}
VM2993:3 Uncaught TypeError: currentSound.get is not a function
    at _.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:47)
    at m (sc.js:1)
    at w (sc.js:1)
(anonymous) @ VM2993:3
m @ sc.js:1
w @ sc.js:1

widget.getCurrentSound(function(ret){console.log(JSON.stringify(ret))});
_ {}
3VM2993:3 Uncaught TypeError: currentSound.get is not a function
    at _.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:47)
    at m (sc.js:1)
    at w (sc.js:1)
(anonymous) @ VM2993:3
m @ sc.js:1
w @ sc.js:1

widget.getCurrentSound(function(ret){console.dir(ret)});
_ {}
VM2993:3 Uncaught TypeError: currentSound.get is not a function
    at _.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:47)
    at m (sc.js:1)
    at w (sc.js:1)
```

Comment: Can you explain what's not working in more detail? Are you getting any errors? And if so, what are they?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody return of getCurrentSound() and getSounds() are not accessible by any of the methods I can think of. The returns are like "currentSound.get is not a function" when I try to log the returned sound object. Is there a proper way of getting use of the returned objects?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how this happened but the code is working fine now.

Maybe the soundcloud server or the API was kind of unstable at the moment.

widget.getSounds() and widget.getCurrentSound() returns JSON string(or array which is interchangable in JS)

and they are formatted just same with ones at https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html